# Why List<T>.Add is a read mechanism in a read-only property?

Tags: c#, properties

Maybe it's just a misunderstanding but this is a big question for me. Let me explain it:

According to [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) a property is a mechanism and not a field. A mechanism that provide read and write functions for a field, and according to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w86s7x04.aspx) we can create a read-only, write-only or read-write property by using `get` and `set` accessors.

Now the implementation is here:

```
public class Foo
{
    private List<string> _bar;

    public List<string> Bar
    {
        get
        {
            return _bar;
        }
    }

    public Foo()
    {
        _bar = new List<string>();
        _bar.Add("string1");
    }
}
```

In `Foo` class we have a read-only property (`Bar`) that consists of one string.

Now lets add a driver for this class:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Foo fooObj = new Foo();
    fooObj.Bar.Add("string2");

    foreach (string s in fooObj.Bar)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();

}
```

And here is the big question mark:
**Why the `Bar` property is not read-only?**

output:

```
srring1
string2
```

I know how to create a read-only collection (my question is not why `List<T>` is not read-only) and I need a explanation about read-only properties.

Comment: It _is_ readonly, try to assign a different list. But all properties of this object can be used. You don't make all properties of this object readonly recursively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay,

A `List<T>` is a reference type.

So, a property

```
List<string> SomeList
{
    get
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

is a read-only property, you cannot set the `SomeList` to a different `List<string>`. Essentially,

```
SomeList = new List<string>();
```

will not compile.

As you note, making a property of a reference type read only does not make that type read only.

If you want a read only list I'd suggest,

```
IReadOnlyList<string> SomeList
{
    get
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Well the `Bar` *property* is read only i.e. it can't be directly set

```
fooObj.Bar = new List<string>(); // compiler error
```

However, the data *returned* by that property isn't

```
fooObj.Bar.Add("..."); // is fine
```

The point to understand is the modifier on a property dictates how it can be *accessed* from the object, it has no direct affect on the underlying data of the property. Therefore, returning a reference type from a read-only property is the exact same as returning a reference type from a read/write property.

In your example, if you wanted the `Bar` to be read-only then you could return a `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` which is an immutable collection, rather than a `List<T>`.

```
private List<string> _bar;
...
public void Add(string item)
{
    _bar.Add(item);
}

public IEnumerable<string> Bar
{
    get { return new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(_bar); }
}
```

This would keep control of the list with the containing object but allow you to return a readonly *copy* of the list itself.

Comment: +1 for your solution, but Jodrell came up with a better explanation. Tanks for your answer.

Comment: @HaMeD could you elaborate on what is *"better"* about Jodrell's explanation? Doesn't appear to be any better than my answer (in my biased opinion, of course).

Comment: Its better to me and it doesn't mean that Jodrell's answer is better than your answer. For a reason I can tell it has a simpler explanation. However there is no "better" answer, both answers are perfect. Tanks again ;)

Comment: @HaMeD Ok so it's simpler in your opinion, what part of my answer was *less* simple to understand? I only ask because if I agree I can improve my answer.

Comment: I said before that your answer is perfect, the part of Jodrell's answer that makes it simpler is this sentence: _"making a property of a reference type read only does not make that type read only"_ and other side on your answer there is this sentence: _"it doesn't have any influence on how the underlying data is manipulated once retrieved."_. In my opinion the first explanation is simpler. Am I wrong?

Comment: @HaMeD of course your not wrong, it's your opinion :) And actually, I agree, I could have been more specific rather than using generic terms like "*influence*". Although, my only defence would be I made it pretty clear at the beginning of the answer that the property itself was read-only but the data itself was not. Regardless, thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Because the *getter* method of your `Bar` property returns the list, and then you are mutating that list.Omitting the *setter* method only prevents you to assign a new list directly like this:

```
fooObj.Bar = new List<string>();
```

If you want to make it immutable you can change return type of your property to `IEnumerable<string>` instead.. Though you can still cast it to list and then mutate...

Answer (score 1):

The `Bar` property *is* read-only. You can only read the list `Bar` points to - you cannot make `Bar` point to some other list.

However, the list itself is *mutable*. You can add or remove items from it.

Eric lippert calls this "shallow immutability" in his blog post [Immutability in C# Part One: Kinds of Immutability](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/11/13/immutability-in-c-part-one-kinds-of-immutability.aspx). The property is read-only, but its contents can change.